# How can I fix log4j error on Matlab startup?

Tags: matlab

I get the below error when starting Matlab. log4j was removed at my company due to security issues. Does the error matter?  If so, what are my options?  I'm on R2020A on Linux.

```
Exception in thread "CFB Source Control Executor": java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Appender
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at com.mathworks.util.ImplementorsCacheImpl.getService(ImplementorsCacheImpl.java:142)
at com.mathworks.util.ImplementorsCacheImpl.getServicesForImplementors(ImplementorsCacheImpl.java:126)
at com.mathworks.util.ImplementorsCacheImpl.getImplementors(ImplementorsCacheImpl.java:61)
at com.mathworks.cmlink.management.registration.OsgiCMAdapterFactoryList.lookUpFactories(OsgiCMAdapterFactoryList.java:35)
at com.mathworks.cmlink.management.registration.OsgiCMAdapterFactoryList.<init>(OsgiCMAdapterFactoryList.java:27)
at com.mathworks.cmlink.management.registration.OsgiCMAdapterFactoryList.<clinit>(OsgiCMAdapterFactoryList.java:17)
at com.mathworks.cmlink.management.registration.SingletonCMAdapterFactoryList.getCMAdapterFactoryLists(SingletonCMAdapterFactoryList.java:32)
at com.mathworks.cmlink.management.registration.SingletonCMAdapterFactoryList.<clinit>(SingletonCMAdapterFactoryList.java:14)
at com.mathworks.cmlink.management.pool.adapter.PrefBackedAdapterFactoryProvider.provide(PrefBackedAdapterFactoryProvider.java:29)
at com.mathworks.cmlink.util.adapter.CMAdapterFactoryProviderDecorator.provide(CMAdapterFactoryProviderDecorator.java:19)
at com.mathworks.cmlink.util.adapter.transformer.TransformableCMAdapterFactoryProvider.provide(TransformableCMAdapterFactoryProvider.java:24)
at com.mathworks.cmlink.util.adapter.CMAdapterFactoryProviderDecorator.provide(CMAdapterFactoryProviderDecorator.java:19)
at com.mathworks.cmlink.util.adapter.transformer.TransformableCMAdapterFactoryProvider.provide(TransformableCMAdapterFactoryProvider.java:24)
at com.mathworks.cmlink.management.pool.PooledCmStatusCacheEntry.<init>(PooledCmStatusCacheEntry.java:77)
at com.mathworks.cmlink.management.pool.PooledCmStatusCacheProvider$1.<init>(PooledCmStatusCacheProvider.java:101)
at com.mathworks.cmlink.management.pool.PooledCmStatusCacheProvider.provideEntryFor(PooledCmStatusCacheProvider.java:98)
at com.mathworks.cmlink.management.pool.PooledCmStatusCacheProvider.provideCacheUnsafe(PooledCmStatusCacheProvider.java:55)
at com.mathworks.cmlink.management.pool.PooledCmStatusCacheProvider.provideCacheFor(PooledCmStatusCacheProvider.java:47)
at com.mathworks.cmlink.management.cache.RootSearchingCmStatusCacheFactory.provideCacheFor(RootSearchingCmStatusCacheFactory.java:38)
at com.mathworks.sourcecontrol.SCAdapterConnectionManager.updateCache(SCAdapterConnectionManager.java:174)
at com.mathworks.sourcecontrol.SCAdapterConnectionManager.access$500(SCAdapterConnectionManager.java:29)
at com.mathworks.sourcecontrol.SCAdapterConnectionManager$2.run(SCAdapterConnectionManager.java:78)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Appender
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 27 more
Exception in thread "CFB Source Control Executor": java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.mathworks.cmlink.management.registration.SingletonCMAdapterFactoryList
    at com.mathworks.cmlink.management.pool.adapter.PrefBackedAdapterFactoryProvider.provide(PrefBackedAdapterFactoryProvider.java:29)
    at com.mathworks.cmlink.util.adapter.CMAdapterFactoryProviderDecorator.provide(CMAdapterFactoryProviderDecorator.java:19)
    at com.mathworks.cmlink.util.adapter.transformer.TransformableCMAdapterFactoryProvider.provide(TransformableCMAdapterFactoryProvider.java:24)
    at com.mathworks.cmlink.util.adapter.CMAdapterFactoryProviderDecorator.provide(CMAdapterFactoryProviderDecorator.java:19)
    at com.mathworks.cmlink.util.adapter.transformer.TransformableCMAdapterFactoryProvider.provide(TransformableCMAdapterFactoryProvider.java:24)
    at com.mathworks.cmlink.management.pool.PooledCmStatusCacheEntry.<init>(PooledCmStatusCacheEntry.java:77)
    at com.mathworks.cmlink.management.pool.PooledCmStatusCacheProvider$1.<init>(PooledCmStatusCacheProvider.java:101)
    at com.mathworks.cmlink.management.pool.PooledCmStatusCacheProvider.provideEntryFor(PooledCmStatusCacheProvider.java:98)
    at com.mathworks.cmlink.management.pool.PooledCmStatusCacheProvider.provideCacheUnsafe(PooledCmStatusCacheProvider.java:55)
    at com.mathworks.cmlink.management.pool.PooledCmStatusCacheProvider.provideCacheFor(PooledCmStatusCacheProvider.java:47)
    at com.mathworks.cmlink.management.cache.RootSearchingCmStatusCacheFactory.provideCacheFor(RootSearchingCmStatusCacheFactory.java:38)
    at com.mathworks.sourcecontrol.SCAdapterConnectionManager.updateCache(SCAdapterConnectionManager.java:174)
    at com.mathworks.sourcecontrol.SCAdapterConnectionManager.access$500(SCAdapterConnectionManager.java:29)
    at com.mathworks.sourcecontrol.SCAdapterConnectionManager$2.run(SCAdapterConnectionManager.java:78)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Probably a question for MathWorks support...

Comment: How about execute with [-nojvm](https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler/matlab-runtime-startup-options.html) option?